# Protracting vowels during speech

Tags: pronunciation

I would like to know why protracting vowels during speech, even in languages that do not have the distinction between short and long vowels, even, perhaps, protracting vowels excessively, even, at different time lengths or with perceived variable number of time repetitions, as you pronounce the various vowels in words in sentences, have, a positive effect, on learning and acquisition (at least, I would think, for most people (let me know if it is not so)).

In any case, does genetics, or teaching methods, play a role (both in acquisition and sound transmission))?

Thanks.

Comment: Any protraction can help people "hear" something they might not otherwise hear. Genetics is irrelevant here.